# Upload Blob(s) from Firebase Storage Emulator to Firebase Cloud Storage

Tags: firebase-storage, firebase-tools

What is the best way to move files stored via the Firebase Storage Emulator up to Firebase Cloud Storage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no specific tool for this. You can either use the Firebase Storage SDK, one of the Google Cloud SDKs for Cloud Storage, or a command-line utility like `gsutil cp`.